# A question about Hölder space and Sobolev

Tags: functional-analysis, holder-spaces

How to find the norms defined on the Hölder space

The Hölder Space $C^{k,\gamma}(\bar{U})$ consisting of the all $u \in C^k(\bar{U})$
for which the norm

$$\|u\|_{C^{k,\gamma}(\bar{U})}:= \sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \|D^\alpha u \|_{C(\bar{U})}+\sum_{|\alpha|=k} [D^\alpha u]_{C^{0,\gamma}(\bar{U})}$$

is finite

**how to find $|u\|_{C^{k,\gamma}(\bar{U})}$**

For example $u(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ then how to find $|u\|_{C^{k,\gamma}(\bar{U})}$

What does this mean $\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \|D^\alpha u \|_{C(\bar{U})},\sum_{|\alpha|=k} [D^\alpha u]_{C^{0,\gamma}(\bar{U})}$ ?

Can you please explain how to find norms of $||u||_{C(\bar{U})}$
 and $[u]_{C^{0,\gamma(\bar{U})}}$

I am stating studying these things and I'm getting confusing

And can some on suggest me where can i get examples such kinds

Thank you so much

Comment: What's your U in the example?

Comment: $$\|D^\alpha u\|_{C(F)} = \sup_{x\in F} |D^\alpha u(x)|$$ and 
$$ [D^\alpha u]_{C^{0,\gamma}(F)} = \sup_{x,y\in F : x\neq y} \frac{|D^\alpha u(x)-D^\alpha u(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma}$$, see e.g. Evans. Maybe try computing a 1D example first

Comment: @calvin khor.. I didn't  find any examples in Evans and I'm following  Evans only

Comment: @JohnMa.......$D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Was not necessarily directing you to an example, but the definition since that was your first question.

Comment: Without knowing explicitly the domain U, it is impossible to find the norm. For example, can you find the maximum of $x^2$ on U when U is not given?

Comment: @JohnMa..yeah correct $D=\{x^2+y^2+z^2=1:x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: Are you sure? Your domain is not an open set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague, but lets compute say $\|u\|_{C^{1,1/2}([0,1]^3)}$. Let $\mathbf x = (x,y,z)$, so that $u(\mathbf x) = |\mathbf x|^2$.

First, we need to compute derivatives of order 1. Its $\nabla u(\mathbf x) = 2\mathbf x$. So 
$$ \sum_{|\alpha| \le 1}\|D^\alpha f\|_{C^0}  = \sup_{\mathbf x\in[0,1]^3} |\mathbf x|^2 + \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|2x| + \sup_{y\in[0,1]}|2y|  + \sup_{z\in[0,1]}|2z| =3+2+2+2 = 9 $$
Next we need $[D^{\alpha} u]_{C^{0,1/2}}$. If $\alpha = (1,0,0)$, then
$$ |D^\alpha u(\mathbf x) - D^\alpha u(\mathbf {\tilde x})| = 2| x-\tilde x| $$
so $$[D^\alpha u]_{C^{0,1/2}} = \sup_{\mathbf x,\mathbf {\tilde x} \in[0,1]^3: \mathbf x \ne \mathbf {\tilde x}} \frac{2|x-\tilde x|}{|\mathbf x - \mathbf {\tilde x}|^{1/2}} = \sup_{x,\tilde x \in [0,1]:x\ne \tilde x} 2|x-\tilde x|^{1/2} = 2$$
Symmetry yields the other holder seminorms, and so
$$ \|u\|_{C^{1,\alpha}} = 9 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 15$$

Comment: .........thanks sir....

Comment: @InverseProblem Hope it helps. You can try to show which Holder spaces something like... $|x|^{1/3} + yz$ belongs to, the kinds of terms that appear are similar but some of the sups may not be finite depending on the Holder parameter

Comment: ...im sorry about my domain i was supposed to give my domain $D=\{x^2+y^2+z^2<1:x,y,z\in R\}$ and thanks for advise and can i find any good book for this concepts

Comment: @InverseProblem as JohnMa indicated,  this domain is not the closure of an open set, as your original post seems to indicate with the notation $\overline U$, so I think you made a mistake. This is why I didn't use this domain. But you can still compute this by similar computations as the above.